# Question about "discharging" yourself before building a PC

Tags: support

I have a question about pc build and avoiding any damage to components while I build it. We don't have any earthing/grounding in our home (so does many others here). So basically whether you have 2 pin or 3 pin plug to plug into socket, it doesn't make any difference. The earth pin (i.e., the 3rd pin is completely useless).

So one solution was buying an anti static wrist strap. But I've read it needs grounding in your home so it would be useless? Even if not, I would like to avoid that.

I'm more interested in other solutions.

Most common people suggest is "touching metal parts in your home" or "touching the pc cabinet itself".

So basically I just want to know how do they work? How do I do it? Does the metal part at my home have to be in direct contact of my room floor?

Similarly, when people say touch pc cabinet (because it's metal), does it have to be on room floor?

Some people say pc cabinet method works when you use PSU installed. But like I said, we don't have any grounding here. So I would avoid that. Would just touching the pc cabinet when nothing is installed in it work?

**So can I ask this question here?**

Comment: We have many questions about electrostatic discharge (ESD) already so it would be worth searching to see if your question already has an answer. https://superuser.com/search?q=esd At the very least most houses (in sensible countries) have earth wiring in the house wiring so you can get [ESD earth plugs](https://www.google.com/search?&q=esd+earth+plug) that allow you to connect a wrist strap to your mains system.

Comment: @Mokubai I couldn't clarify my doubts through old questions. They focused on anti static wrist bands and grounding at home etc.

Comment: Also most of them assume we have grounding at home. (i.e., the earth wiring)

Comment: they do indeed assume that houses have earth wiring, because all houses *should* have earth wiring. It is a critical safety feature that can literally save lives. RCDs may prevent a life threatening shock, but an effective ground can have made the device safe long before you get that shock. If you are in a place with no safe earthing system then ESD straps and any other precautions will be basically useless as you have nothing to connect them to, you might as well just blow up a load of balloons, put on your best nylon shirt and hope the computer works by the time you are finished.

Comment: So basically this question won't fit here :(

Comment: @Vikas - "I couldn't clarify my doubts through old questions." - So you can ask the question but be sure you explain in detail, the reason the existing answers that do exist, do not answer your question.  You will have to be prepared for the community to disagree with you. In order to protect your hardware, anti-static straps, simple require the device you are working on and yourself to be connected to the same ground.  Researching on how ESD works, and showing you understand the concept, i.e. you build a charge and then touch something that has a lesser charge would be helpful.